# how to convert the python regex into js regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Python regex pattern

```
pattern = r'^(?:(.*?) )?(https?:\/\/\S+) (.*)$|^(?:(.*?) )?(SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____\S+) ?(.*)$'
```

how to convert this same `regex` into `js regex` ?

Any Help would  be Appreciated thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read about **RegExp** validation before implementing https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

and then try below code

```
var pattern = /^(?:(.*?) )?(https?:\/\/\S+) (.*)$|^(?:(.*?) )?(SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____\S+) ?(.*)$/;
var string = 'test string';
// validate 
pattern.test(string)
```

Comment: thanks @Nagesh Sanika for the help